# SQL Database Design for monthly issued coupons

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm struggling with a database schema for a problem I'm having.

Let's say I own a business that sells monthly services (cleaning) to different companies. 
However, I give companies monthly saveable 'coupons' that act like a reduction (of 5 dollars) based on their amount of users.

Example:

It's april 2018
Company XYZ has to pay 1.000 dollars for their monthly cleaning services by my business. 
XYZ, has 5 employees, so they will have 5 coupons for the month of april.

HOWEVER, since coupons can be saved (for a period of 2 months), company XYZ will not use the coupons of only april, but also of march (since they didn't use any that month and february coupons are already used up).

Result: 
10 coupons are used on their april invoice (5 of march, 5 of april):
total amount to pay 950 dollars

---

My thing is that I want to automate this. With one click on the button, my system will have to check:

- How many users there are

  - If there are any unused coupons from last 2 months (and use those first if they exist)
  - Apply coupons to their invoice.

---

I want to design this first in a database but i'm struggling:

This is my design

- Company

  - CompanyID
  - Name
- User

  - UserID
  - CompanyID
  - UserID

Now I'm struggling with the coupon design, how can I develop this so that I can automise my problem. 
I will need to save coupons per company per month.

My idea is to do it like this:

- Company_Month_Coupon

  - CompanyID
  - Coupon_Count
  - Month

I wasn't sure if i could do this in one table and i'm not so sure with the following problem:

- what if my program user decides to cancel an invoice, how would my system know from which month the coupons came?

What design would be adviced in a coupon-sharing system?

Any advice to tackling this problem would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with your idea and have 2 more tables: `Invoices` and `Invoices_UsedCoupons`

`Invoices`:

- ID (Primary key)
- CompanyID
- Month
- Status (to set a cancelled status on your invoice if you don't want to delete from the DB)

`Invoices_UsedCoupons`:

- InvoiceId (foreign key to `Invoices` table)
- Coupon_Count
- Month (this field is for the used coupons from `Company_Month_Coupon` table)

The reasons for this:

- We should still store the issued coupons (in your `Company_Month_Coupon` table) because for each month, the number of employees may change. It means that you have to keep track of the issued coupons whenever the number of employees changes.
- With `Invoices` and `Invoices_UsedCoupons` table, you could easily calculate the actual used coupons & the remaining coupons.

> what if my program user decides to cancel an invoice, how would my
>   system know from which month the coupons came?

All the information is available in `Invoices` and `Invoices_UsedCoupons` tables. If you want to reclaim coupons after cancelling the invoice, it's also easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

"I will need to save coupons per company per month."

Maybe you can do the opposite. In the database does not store coupons that can be used, but only those that are actually used, for example in the table "used_coupons"

The idea is that the coupons are given up by default, so it makes no sense to store them. Only need to save the used coupons.

At checkout you need to find out how much users is in the company and how many "used coupons" is saved in the last two months.

If X coupons are returned then from the "used_coupons" table you need to delete the latest X coupons.